# How to get only manual excerpts?

Tags: excerpt

I have a plugin I'm modifying in which I need to return the manual excerpt if it exists, and if not, nothing. How would I go about that? Here's my code so far:

```
            $excerpts = sprintf(
                '<a href="%1$s">Apply</a>',
                esc_attr( sprintf( __( '%s' ), get_the_excerpt() ) ),
                get_the_excerpt()
            );
```

It works, but it only returns the automatically generated excerpt. Is there an argument for get_the_excerpt() to do what I want?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `$post->post_excerpt` holds the manual one and `the_excerpt()` will generate it if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question. Solved with an if else statement using has_excerpt.

```
            if( has_excerpt ( $_post, ID ) ) {
                 $author = sprintf( '<a href="%1$s">Apply</a>', esc_attr( get_the_excerpt( $_post ) ) );
            } else {
                 $author = '';
            }
```

It only makes sense, really.